# converting XMLHTTPRequest into $ajax

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am fetching Google in a gadget using this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Browser</title>
</head>
<body onload= "getListCollection()" style="width:900px; height:900px;" >
<div id="listAttributes" style="width:400px; height:400px;" ></div>
<script>

function getListCollection() {
    var url = "https://www.google.co.uk"  
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true, 'user', 'password');
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4);
        {
            document.getElementById("listAttributes").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder how can I do the same thing using $ajax?

I looked at different examples but I don't know how they gonna fit in this situation. Or if you can post some nice $ajax tutorials please.

When I change it to this, it doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Browser</title>
</head>
<body onload= "getListCollection()" style="width:900px; height:900px;" >
<div id="listAttributes" style="width:400px; height:400px;" ></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">

$.ajax({
    url : 'https://www.google.co.uk',
    type : 'GET',
    success : function(data){
        $('#listAttributes').html(data);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing comes up on the page.

Comment: Do you mean `$.ajax()`? Start with the documentation.

Comment: What is `$ajax`? You've tagged this `jquery` so do you mean `$.ajax`?  Have you tried looking at the tutorials on the jQuery site?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a jQuery version of the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://www.google.co.uk', //cross-domain? this won't work
    username : 'user',
    password : 'password',
    type : 'GET', //default is GET, but i put it here to clarify
    success : function(data){
        $('#listAttributes').html(data);
    }
});
```

For more details and settings, read the [`jQuery.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: If i will use it, i probably gonna need to reference jquery as well

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://www.google.co.uk",
    type : "get",
    username : "user",
    password : "password",
    success : function(data) {
        document.getElementById("listAttributes").innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```

However, your code most probably won't work since you are trying to access the external resource (i.e. not your domain).

Check the [JQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for further details.

Comment: I am making this gadget for clients who will connect to domain from outside, I wonder if it doesn't work like XMLHTTPRequest

Comment: @TimeToThine Yes. The browser will not give you to do this. For cross-domain Ajax requests you can use [JSONP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) as an option.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   username: 'user',
   password: 'password'
}).done(function (responseText) {
   document.getElementById('listAttributes').innerHTML = responseText;
   //or
   $("#listAttributes").html(responseText);
});
```

By default, `.ajax` will use the GET method and be asynchronous, so I omitted those settings.  If you don't need the username/password, I would use `$.get()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple and shorter than the pure JavaScript version, here it is:

```
function getListCollection() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.google.co.uk",
        username: "user",
        password: "password",
        success: function(data){
            $('listAttributes').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The request is only accepted if the site supports cross-domain origin.
Check the [jQuery.ajax() documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).