# How to convert XMLHttpRequest() to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I usually use ajax, but never had to send files with it before. My initial research indicated you couldn't send files with ajax so I found and used this method; but later research indicated it was possible to send a file with ajax.

Now I'm concerned about changing it because everything is working at the moment and I still don't understand how html/jscript treats files. So I'm wondering, how can this function be converted to Ajax in a way that will not require me to change to change the upload_metric_post.php code?

```
function uploadMetric(file){
    var MetricID = $("#MetricID").val();
    var ReportPeriod = $("#ReportPeriod").val();
    if(MetricID == ""){
        $("#upload_results").addClass("alert-danger");
        $("#upload_results").removeClass("alert-success");
        $("#upload_results").html("Please select the MetricID before uploading.");
    }else{
        var url = 'php/upload_metric_post.php';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                // Request went thru ok, handle response.
                var response = xhr.responseText;
                console.log(response);
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);

                if(jsonResponse["success"] == false){
                    var errors = jsonResponse["msg"] + jsonResponse["error"];
                    $("#upload_results").addClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#upload_results").removeClass("alert-success");
                    $("#upload_results").html(errors);
                    $("#dropped_rows_panel").html(jsonResponse["bad_rows"]);
                    $("#start_over_btn").show();
                    $("#process_btn").hide();
                }else if(jsonResponse["success"] == true){
                    $("#upload_results").addClass("alert-success");
                    $("#upload_results").removeClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#upload_results").html(jsonResponse["msg"]);
                    $("#dropped_rows_panel").html(jsonResponse["bad_rows"]);
                    $("#start_over_btn").show();
                    $("#process_btn").show();
                }
            }
        };
        fd.append("MetricID", MetricID);
        fd.append("ReportPeriod", ReportPeriod);
        fd.append("upload_file", file);
        xhr.send(fd);
    }
}
```

Here is the standard I use throughout my code, never having to had send a file before, I do not really know how to convert it to my standard:

```
function get_assets(display_qty, go_page, sorts, sorts_order, filters_ordered, CallBack) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "php/assets_post.php",
        data: {
            display_qty: display_qty,
            go_page: go_page,
            sorts: sorts,
            sorts_order: sorts_order,
            filters_ordered: filters_ordered
        },
        success: function(result){
            CallBack(result);
        },
        error: function(result){
            CallBack(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: There is similar questions and if you look at that first it will help you. Here is the link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654429/converting-xmlhttprequest-into-ajax

Comment: Looks like both ways are using AJAX to process the request. xhr.open etc. are the plain old javascript way of writing an AJAX call. The method you list using $.ajax is the jquery method. I like it, it's cleaner so I usually write mine in jquery but they do the same thing so if it's working now...

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest and AJAX are the same thing.  Ajax you're referring to may be jQuery's function named ajax for implementing an async call to a server endpoint.   jQuery actually wraps the XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

Even your code is ajax, if are looking for jquery ajax syntax for your code just do the following:

$.ajax({  method: "POST",  url: "php/upload_metric_post.php", })  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {      var response = xhr.responseText;   console.log(response);     var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);    ---and the rest is same---  });

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution, it relies on sending the data to ajax as a FormData object. contentType and processData settings are critical as it doesn't work without them; why it doesn't work without them I do not know:

```
function uploadMetric(file){
    var MetricID = $("#MetricID").val();
    var ReportPeriod = $("#ReportPeriod").val();
    if(MetricID == ""){
        $("#upload_results").addClass("alert-danger");
        $("#upload_results").removeClass("alert-success");
        $("#upload_results").html("Please select the MetricID before uploading.");
    }else{
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("MetricID", MetricID);
        fd.append("ReportPeriod", ReportPeriod);
        fd.append("upload_file", file);
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "php/upload_metric_post.php",
            data: fd,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(result);
                if(jsonResponse["success"] == false){
                    var errors = jsonResponse["msg"] + jsonResponse["error"];
                    $("#upload_results").addClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#upload_results").removeClass("alert-success");
                    $("#upload_results").html(errors);
                    $("#dropped_rows_panel").html(jsonResponse["bad_rows"]);
                    $("#start_over_btn").show();
                    $("#step3_intructions").html(errors + "<br />Please check your file, fix any errors and start over.");
                    $("#step3_intructions").addClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#step3_intructions").removeClass("alert-success");
                    $("#step3_intructions").show();
                    $("#process_btn").hide();
                }else if(jsonResponse["success"] == true){
                    $("#ReportPeriod").attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $("#MetricID").attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $("#fileinput").attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $("#fileinput_label").attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $("#upload_results").addClass("alert-success");
                    $("#upload_results").removeClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#upload_results").html(jsonResponse["msg"]);
                    $("#dropped_rows_panel").html(jsonResponse["bad_rows"]);
                    $("#start_over_btn").show();
                    $("#step3_intructions").html("<p>Please review any dropped rows. If there are no dropped rows and you are ready to process the metric, press 'Process Metric'. If there are dropped rows you have the following options:<p><ol><li>Correct the rows in the original file you uploaded, re-upload and check the dropped rows again or,</li><li>if you are okay with the dropped rows you may process the accepted rows anyway.</li></ol>");
                    $("#step3_intructions").addClass("alert-success");
                    $("#step3_intructions").removeClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#step3_intructions").show();
                    $("#process_btn").show();
                }
                CallBack(result);
            },
            error: function(result){
                alert("mm");
                CallBack(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```